# Create a variable and apllying a function to another one

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column Arrivo (formatted as date) and a column Giorni (formatted as integer) with number of days (es.: 2, 3, 6 etc..).
I would like to apply two function to these columns and precisely, I would like to duplicate a row for the number in the column Giorni and while duplicating these rows, I would like to create a new column called data.osservazione that is equal to Arrivo and augmented of one day iteratively.

From this:

```
    No.  Casa Anno       Data Categoria Camera     Arrivo Stornata.il Giorni
1   2.867 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 28/03/2020          NA      3
2 148.000 SEELE 2020 20/01/2020       CDS    105 29/03/2020          NA      3
3   3.684 SEELE 2019 16/11/2019        CD    102 02/04/2020          NA      5
```

to this:

```
No. data.osservazione  Casa Anno       Data Categoria Camera            Arrivo
1 2867         3/28/2020 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 3/28/2020 0:00:00
2 2867         3/29/2020 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 3/28/2020 0:00:00
3 2867         3/30/2020 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 3/28/2020 0:00:00
4  148         3/29/2020 SEELE 2020 20/01/2020       CDS    105 3/29/2020 0:00:00
5  148         3/30/2020 SEELE 2020 20/01/2020       CDS    105 3/29/2020 0:00:00
6  148         3/31/2020 SEELE 2020 20/01/2020       CDS    105 3/29/2020 0:00:00
  Stornata.il Giorni
1        #N/D      3
2        #N/D      3
3        #N/D      3
4        #N/D      3
```

I was able to duplicate the rows but I don't know how to concurrently create the new column with the values I need.

Please don't mind the date values in the columns, I'll fix them in the end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use `dput(head(data))` where `data` is the name of  your example's `data.frame` . Paste the result to your question. `dput()` allows us to work with the exact data you're working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am a fan of the `data.table` package, I will propose a solution using `data.table`. You can install it by typing on the console: `install.packages("data.table")`.

My approach was to create a separate `data.frame` with an index going from `0` to whatever number is in `Giorni` **by row** from the original `data.frame` and then merge this new `data.frame` with the original data that you have and, by virtue of many to one matches from the key specified, the resulting `data.frame` will "expand" to the size desired, therefore "duplicating" the rows when necessary.

For this, I used `seq_len()`. If you do `seq_len(3L)`, you get: `[1] 1 2 3` which is the sequence from `1L` to whatever integer you've given in `length.out` when `length.out >= 1L`. Thus `seq_len()` will produce a sequence that ends in whatever is in `Giorni`, the challenge is to do by row since `length.out` in `seq_len()` needs to be a vector of size 1. We use `by` in `data.table` syntax to accomplish this.

So let's get started, first you load `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) # load data.table

setDT(data) # data.frame into data.table
```

In your example, it isn't clear whether `Arrivo` is in `Date` format, I am assuming it isn't so I convert to `Date` --you will need this to add the days later.

```
# is `Arrivo`` date? If no, into date fmt
data[["Arrivo"]] <- as.Date(data[["Arrivo"]], format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

The next bit is key, using `seq_len()` and `by` in `data.table` syntax, I create a separate `data.table` --which is always a `data.frame`, but not the other way around-- with the sequence by every single element of `Giorni`, therefore expanding the data to the desired size. I use `by = "No."` because I want to apply `seq_len()` to every value of `Giorni` associated with `No.` the values in `No.`.

```
# create an index with the count from `Giorni`, subtract by 1 so the first day is 0.
d1 <- data[, seq_len(Giorni) - 1, by = "No."]
```

Check the result, you can see where I am going now:

```
> d1
    No. V1
1: 2867  0
2: 2867  1
3: 2867  2
4:  148  0
5:  148  1
```

Lastly, you inner join `d1` with the original data, I am using `data.table` join syntax here. Then you add the index `V1` to `Arrivo`:

```
# merge with previous data
res <- d1[data, on = "No."]

# add days to `Arrivo``, create column data.osservazione
res[ , data.osservazione := V1 + Arrivo]
```

Result:

```
> res
    No. V1  Casa Anno       Data Categoria Camera     Arrivo
1: 2867  0 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
2: 2867  1 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
3: 2867  2 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
4:  148  0 SEELE 2019 20/01/2020       CDS    105 2020-03-29
5:  148  1 SEELE 2019 20/01/2020       CDS    105 2020-03-29
   Stornata.il Giorni data.osservazione
1:          NA      3        2020-03-28
2:          NA      3        2020-03-29
3:          NA      3        2020-03-30
4:          NA      2        2020-03-29
5:          NA      2        2020-03-30
```

The next commands are just cosmetic, formatting dates and deleting columns:

```
# reformat `Arrivo` and `data.osservazione`
cols <- c("Arrivo", "data.osservazione")
res[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) format(x=x, format="%d/%m/%Y")), .SDcols=cols]

# remove index
res[, V1 := NULL]
```

Console:

```
> res
    No. V1  Casa Anno       Data Categoria Camera     Arrivo
1: 2867  0 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
2: 2867  1 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
3: 2867  2 SEELE 2019 03/09/2019       CDV    316 2020-03-28
4:  148  0 SEELE 2019 20/01/2020       CDS    105 2020-03-29
5:  148  1 SEELE 2019 20/01/2020       CDS    105 2020-03-29
   Stornata.il Giorni data.osservazione
1:          NA      3        2020-03-28
2:          NA      3        2020-03-29
3:          NA      3        2020-03-30
4:          NA      2        2020-03-29
5:          NA      2        2020-03-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @JdeMello and really thank you for the quick answer!

Indeed it was what I was looking for, but in the mean time I kinda found a solution myself using lubridate and tidyverse and purrr.
What I did was transform variables from Posix to date (revenue is my df):

```
revenue <- revenue %>% mutate(Data = as_date(Data), Arrivo = as_date(Arrivo), `Stornata il` = as_date(`Stornata il`), Partenza = as_date(Partenza))
```

Then I created another data frame but included variables id and data_obs:

```
revenue_1 <- revenue %>%  mutate(data_obs = Arrivo, id = 1:nrow(revenue))
```

I created another data frame with the variable data_obs iterated by the number of Giorni:

```
revenue_2 <- revenue_1 %>% group_by(id, data_obs) %>% 
  complete(Giorni = sequence(Giorni)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(data_obs = data_obs + Giorni -1)
```

I extracted data_obs:

```
data_obs <- revenue_2$data_obs
```

I created another data frame to duplicate the rows:

```
revenue_3 <- revenue %>% map_df(.,rep, .$Giorni)
```

And finally created the ultimate data frame that I needed:

```
revenue_finale <- revenue_3 %>% mutate(data_obs = data_obs)
```

I know it's kinda redundant having created all those data frame but I have very little knowledge of R at the moment and had to work around.
I wanted to merge data frames but for unknown reasons to me, it didn't work out.

What I found kinda fun is that you can play with many packages to get to your point instead of using just one. 
I've never used data.table so your answer is very interesting and I'll try to memorize it.

So again, really really thank you!!

Comment: There are many ways to approach your problem. Glad you arrived at a solution on your own.